# Exponential distribution question for n items

Tags: probability-theory, exponential-distribution

The length of a piece of string extruded from a machine without breakage is an
exponential random variable with mean 30 metres. What is the (approximate)
probability that the average length of 60 pieces will be between 28 and 34
metres?

I know how to do it if it was for a string. I do not know how to go about it with respect to the 60 strings.

For one string, between 28 and 34 I can simply integrate the pdf to get the probability.

Comment: Try using Central Limit Theorem.

Comment: I know how to solve the normal exponential distribution. But I do not know what to do with the n items.

Comment: The lifetime of a computer component is modelled by an exponential random
variable, X, with an expectation of 100 days. A batch contains 50 components.What is the (approximate) probability that the average lifetime of the
components in the batch is greater than 110 days? (You may assume that the
lifetimes of components are independent of one another.) Have a very similar question out here

Comment: The exponential has variance $30^2$. If $W$ is the average length of $60$ randomly selected pieces, then $W$ has approximately normal distribution, mean $30$, variance $\frac{900}{60}$,

Answer (score 1):

Hint/outline:

1. Consider the $i$th string. Its length $X_i$ follows a _____ distribution?
2. Do you have just one string? No, you have 60. Assume they are all independent.
3. Are you interested in their sum? No, you want the average, call it $\bar X$.
4. Thus you want $P(20<\bar X< 38)$ Since you have 60 strings, then $\bar X$ is approximately normal by the CLT. So you need the mean of $\bar X$ and variance of $\bar X$. What are they?
5. Calculate like you would a regular normal distribution.